# C#: Using Reflection to dynamically call an explicitly implemented method

Tags: c#, reflection, invoke

I am trying to dynamically call an explicitly implemented method using reflection. My method is as follows:

```
public static double GetValueOfAverage(string typeName, string methodName, object[] arguments){
    // ... get the Type for the class
    Type calledType = Type.GetType(typeName, true);

    double avg  = (double)calledType.InvokeMember(
        methodName,
        BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | 
        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
        null,
        null,
        new object[] { arguments }
    );

    // Return the value returned by the called method.
    return avg;
}
```

I call this method as follows:

```
// ... calculate and set the slow moving average value
var slowArguments = new object[] { SlowPeriod, CurrentBar, Input, slowAverage};
movingAvg = GetValueOfAverage("MovingAverage", slowAvgMethod, slowArguments);
```

And my moving average class is implemented as follows:

```
public static class MovingAverage{
    public static double _EMA(int Period, int CurrentBar, DataSeries Input, DataSeries average){
        double avg = CurrentBar == 0 ? Input[0] : Input[0] * (2.0 / (1 + Period)) + (1 - (2.0 / (1 + Period))) * average[1];
        return avg;
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

Could not load type 'MovingAverage' from assembly 'f9e1d550bd4d44ddbdc78abaffa07d31, Version=7.0.1000.22, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I have tried adding the namespace to the class specification but that did not work either. What I did is as follows:

In the GetValueOfAverage method, I inserted the following code

```
var methodInfo = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
var fullName = methodInfo.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + methodInfo.Name;
string str = methodInfo.DeclaringType.FullName + ".";
```

before the line

```
Type calledType = Type.GetType(typeName, true);
```

and replaced the line

```
Type calledType = Type.GetType(typeName, true);
```

with

```
Type calledType = Type.GetType(str+typeName, true);
```

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong? Any suggestions and/or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is that class in the calling assembly?

Comment: @wbennett: Yes it is.

Comment: Full namespace is required. When you added that, are you 100% `fullName`'s value has the correct namespace?

Comment: @mxmissile: Yes. I tried it again and I explicitlytyped in the namespace (and checked that it was typed correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For code loading class, please try to specify namespace like in example below:

```
movingAvg = GetValueOfAverage("ConsoleApplication1.MovingAverage", slowAvgMethod, slowArguments);
```

It may be still not enough if type is located in assembly that is currently not loaded yet.
In this situation you may need to specify type with assembly qualified name like below:

```
movingAvg = GetValueOfAverage("ConsoleApplication1.MovingAverage, ConsoleApplication1", slowAvgMethod, slowArguments);
```

(where first ConsoleApplication1. is namespace, and second ConsoleApplication1 is assembly name)

Finally, you have a mistake in code calling method via reflection, where arguments are passed as nested object[] array. **Arguments** parameter is already passed as object[] so it should be passed directly to InvokeMember() method:

```
double avg  = (double)calledType.InvokeMember(
               methodName,
               BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | 
               BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
               null,
               null,
               arguments);
```

I have updated this post with full example to visualize how to pass type.
The code below is compiled to ConsoleApplication1.exe

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class MovingAverage
    {
        public static double MyMethod(int Period, int CurrentBar, int[] Input, int[] average)
        {
            return 5;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var arguments = new object[] { 1, 2, new[] { 2 }, new[] { 4 } };

            Console.WriteLine(GetValueOfAverage("MyNamespace.MovingAverage", "MyMethod", arguments)); //if assembly is already loaded
            Console.WriteLine(GetValueOfAverage("MyNamespace.MovingAverage, ConsoleApplication1", "MyMethod", arguments)); //if assembly is not loaded yet
            Console.WriteLine(GetValueOfAverage(typeof(MovingAverage), "MyMethod", arguments)); //known type
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static double GetValueOfAverage(string typeName, string methodName, object[] arguments)
        {
            // ... get the Type for the class
            Type calledType = Type.GetType(typeName, true);
            return GetValueOfAverage(calledType, methodName, arguments);
        }

        public static double GetValueOfAverage(Type calledType, string methodName, object[] arguments)
        {
            double avg = (double)calledType.InvokeMember(
                           methodName,
                           BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public |
                           BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                           null,
                           null,
                           arguments);

            // Return the value returned by the called method.
            return avg;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did not catch the error with the arguments. Thank you for pointing it out. How do I get the name of the assembly to use as the second ConsoleApplication1?

Comment: It is usually a name of project in which you have MovingAverage source file located. If the code is compiled to executable or dll, the assembly name is usually a name of dll/exe without extension.

Of course it can be customized in Visual studio:
you have to go to properies of your poject and in Application tab there would be Assembly name field

Comment: Is there a way to get this via code? Would this be the calling assembly or the executing assembly?

Comment: I do not get your question exactly. You can always do typeof(MovingAverage) and just pass it to GetValueOfAverage() instead of typeName, so Type.GetType() would be no longer needed.

But then what would be the point of using reflection to call it, if you know exactly the type :)

Comment: I have tried and it did not work. I will try this again. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the code you posted. I tried it and there is no longer an issue with the calledType. However, I now get the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. The error comes from the double avg = (double)calledType.InvokeMember() portion of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fully qualify the MovingAverage type

```
Type.GetType("MovingAverage");
```

won't work unless you have overridden the TypeResolve event.

You need to use

```
Type.GetType("MovingAverageNamespace.MovingAverage, MovingAverageDllWithoutExtension");
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I apologize for my lack of understanding but MovingAverage is an implemented class so why do I need to use MovingAverageDllWithoutExtension?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it froze the program. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.